# Removing duplicate digits in an integer

Tags: java, arrays, int

I have faced this program in technical round. They have give this program to me for removing duplicate digits in given integer **without using arrays or strings**.

Example:

```
int i = 123134254;
```

Expected output: `12345`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an interview question

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky Why does that make it off-topic?

Comment: To mark it as off topic, I think the most suitable reason is "Lack of effort". If someone posts an interview question and shows his effort in trying to solve the problem, it's on topic IMO. The fact that it's an interview question doesn't make it off-topic.

Comment: I agree "lack of effort" would have been a better reason. I was objecting to the "here's the question; what's the answer" format.

Comment: @user3691208 can collections be used ?

Comment: Even off-topic it catches my attention because I like that kind of questions. I guess collections are also excluded ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use an `int` as a set to store the digits you've already encountered by assigning each digit (0,1,2,...,9) to a bit of said `int`. You can then loop over the digits of `i` and build a new number of solely unique digits by consulting this set. Note that I first reverse the digits of `i` so I can easily loop over them in-order:

```
int i = 123134254;
int res = 0;  // result

int set = 0;  // digits we've seen
int rev = 0;  // digits of `i` reversed

while (i > 0) {
    rev = (rev * 10) + (i % 10);
    i /= 10;
}

while (rev > 0) {
    final int mod = rev % 10;
    final int mask = 1 << mod;
    if ((set & mask) == 0) {
        res = (res * 10) + mod;
        set |= mask;
    }
    rev /= 10;
}

System.out.println(res);
```

```
12345
```

Comment: Yeah, I've already seen that trick, funny way to use bit-wise operations

Comment: +1 for avoiding use of Collections.

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the digits of i using the `%` and `/` operators.

`d0 = i % 10` is the LSB digit
`d1 = ((i - d0) / 10) % 10` is the second digit
...
and so on.

This would give you all the digits from the right to the left.

Since you are not allowed to put them in an array, lets put them in a Stack (hopefully that's allowed). This would allow you to pop them from the Stack from left to right.

For each digit you pop from the Stach, store it in a Set of duplicates, and only if it wasn't already in that Set, output it.

Now, to create output int, each time you output a digit you modify the output this way :

`output = output * 10 + digit;`

Answer (score 1):

1: reverse the number
2: get the last digit 1 by 1
3: check this digit with all the digits from answer
4: if no repeat found add it in answer

```
int i = 123134254;
int copy = 0;
while (i > 0) {
    copy = (copy * 10) + (i % 10);
    i /= 10;
}
int dig = copy % 10;
int ans = dig;
copy /= 10;
while (copy > 0) {
    boolean flag = false;
    dig = copy % 10;
    long copy2 = ans;
    while (copy2 > 0) {
        if (copy2 % 10 == dig) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
        copy2 /= 10;
    }
    if (!flag) {
        ans = ans * 10 + dig;
    }
    copy /= 10;
}
System.out.println(ans);
```